# JS (JQuery) - is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Actually i am not js developer. Have some problems with getting elements (select.value)
My browser said me: Uncaught ReferenceError: getprice is not defined

As i can understand jquery can get by id select.value of elements. How i can fix it?
Thanks!

Js code:

```
function getprice() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=Core_Config::$Link?>store/cart",
        data: {
            pay_type: $("#pay_type").val();,
            delivery_type: $("#delivery_type").val();,
            totalprice: "<?=$total?>"
        },

        success: function(html) {
            $("#content22").html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Html:

```
<tr>
    <td><span class="required">*</span> Delivery:</td>
    <td>
        <select name="address[delivery]" id="delivery_type">
        <? foreach ($this->db->query($this->delivery) as $delivery ): ?>
          <option value="<?=$delivery['id']?>"><?=$delivery['name']?> (<?=$delivery['cost']?> грн)</option>
        <? endforeach; ?>
      </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span class="required">*</span> Payment:</td>
    <td>
        <select name="address[paytype]" id="pay_type" onchange="getprice();">
        <? foreach ($this->db->query($this->payType) as $paytype ): ?>
            <option value="<?=$paytype['id']?>"><?=$paytype['name']?> (<?=$paytype['cost']?> грн)</option>
        <? endforeach; ?>
     </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you added script with the getprice function to this website?

Comment: @PiotrCzarnecki javascript is always exposed to the users in client side (let's not talk about node for now) so I see no objections

Comment: @Thomas - I don't understand your remark, basically I just asked if this script is for sure included. Maybe it wasn't included in html or bundle etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getprice() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=Core_Config::$Link?>store/cart",
        data: {
            pay_type: $("#pay_type").val(), //<--removed ;
            delivery_type: $("#delivery_type").val(), //<--removed ; also
            totalprice: "<?=$total?>"
        },

        success: function(html) {
            $("#content22").html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
   <td><span class="required">*</span> Delivery:</td>
   <td><select name="address[delivery]" id="delivery_type">
       <? foreach ($this->db->query($this->delivery) as $delivery ): ?>
            <option value="<?=$delivery['id']?>"><?=$delivery['name']?> (<?=$delivery['cost']?> грн)</option>
        <? endforeach; ?>
        </select> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span class="required">*</span> Payment:</td>
    <td><select name="address[paytype]" id="pay_type" onchange="getprice();">
           <? foreach ($this->db->query($this->payType) as $paytype ): ?>
                   <option value="<?=$paytype['id']?>"><?=$paytype['name']?> (<?=$paytype['cost']?> грн)</option>
                            <? endforeach; ?>
               </select> </td>
                </tr>
```

It works if you include jQuery!

Comment: Just mistake with using ';' now it's work. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you used latest jquery in you html? Might this comes due to conflict as well put the get price javascript code at bottom of html.

Use latest jquery file in your code 
https://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

It's because the browser could not find the method getprice() definition.

Are you sure, you have included that getprice() function definition in the page. If not please keep that function at the bottom of the file within `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getprice() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=Core_Config::$Link?>store/cart",
        data: {
            pay_type: $("#pay_type").val();,
            delivery_type: $("#delivery_type").val();,
            totalprice: "<?=$total?>"
        },

        success: function(html) {
            $("#content22").html(html);
        }
    });
}
<script>
```